# Remove extra separators from part of a string

Tags: r

I have a data frame that has remant separators from NA columns like:

```
df <- data.frame("row" = c(1:5), "values" = c("A,B,C,,,,,,", "D,E,F,,,,", "A,C,,,,", "B,E,F,,", "G,E,A,,,,,,,,,"))
```

How do I remove the variable number of commas at the end of each value? Is there something in stringr?

Answer (score 5):

We can use `trimws` from `base R`

```
df$values <- trimws(df$values, whitespace = ",+")
df$values
#[1] "A,B,C" "D,E,F" "A,C"   "B,E,F" "G,E,A"
```

---

or using `sub` from `base R`

```
df$values <- sub(",+$", "", df$values)
```

---

In `stringr`, we can use `str_remove`

```
library(stringr)
df$values <- str_remove(df$values, ",+$")
```